# Checking image exists with AJAX request - can't get around MIME type check

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, mime-types

I want to load an image and if it exists then pop it into a DIV.

```
img_width = 350;
img_height = 350;
img = "http://assets.absolutdrinks.com/drinks/transparent-background-white/"+img_width+"x"+img_height+"/" + drink.id + ".png";
img_html = "<div class='drink_img' id='"+drink.id+"_img'></div>";


$.ajax({
    url:img,
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',         
    success:function(img){
        $("#" + drink.id + "_img").html("<img src = '"+ img +"'>");
    },
    error:function(err){
        console.log(err.status + " " + err.statusText);
        $("#" + drink.id + "_img").addClass('no_img');
    },
    cache:true,
    dataType:'jsonp'
});
```

I've ran into two problems, one is that if the type is set as `image/png` (or anything other than `jsonp`) then Chrome's origin control stops it. Setting it to jsonp then adds '?callback=..' to the image url - resulting in the image not being loaded. By adding the options

```
cache:true, 
jsonp: false,
jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback'
```

This then uses the right url but now I get

```
Refused to execute script from -- because its MIME type ('image/png') is not executable.
```

I've added the nosniff HTTP header to the page but still no luck.

Comment: Can you show your `jsonpCallback` please

Comment: Never mind that part actually - removing it still gives the same result. (I hadn't defined it as I've been madly copying things from others solutions trying to solve this seemingly simple problem)

Comment: You're being stopped by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You will either need to use a server-side proxy or add an `img` element to the page with the `src` set the the asset you require, and check the `load()` event for errors to achieve what you require.

Comment: @Supertod do you understand what jsonp is and how it works?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst not in depth. I have just read that you can use jsonp to circumvent Chrome's Same Origin Policy.